# how to fetch events from google calender using API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

If i write some events in Google Calender 
ex: 3 to 4 events how do i start the python program to fetch all these events using google API?

```
event = service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId').execute()

print event['summary']
```

Comment: Hope this will be helpful: https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars

Comment: A good place to start would be a basic python tutorial followed by  [Python quickstart Google calendar api](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python')

Answer (score 0):

Step1. you need calendar id.

Step2. you need google credential. That enables google  calendar api's functions

```
#this code you can use at google app engine
def get_service():
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    return service
```

step3 Then call list function of events

```
 service = get_service()
 events = service.events().list(calendarId='calendarId').execute()
```

Reference https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list